# How make a discord bot print every element of an associative array in one message?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

On my server i have a sistem of coins like this:

```
coin = []

if(msg.content === !coin){
    coin[msg.author.discriminator] = 1 //i found this way to make an array with exclusive values for each user
    msg.reply('now you have a gold coin :)')
}
```

Now here's the problem: i need bot send me in a single message every object of the array to create an database, and send something like this:

```
if(msg.content === '!usercoin'){

   msg.reply(coin[numbers != null]}



bot's reply: 1234:1 , 1235:1, 4444:1, 9999:1 //exemple that i need
```

Comment: Hi kirazeth, I think you are thinking of a for loop here, try doing a for loop that itterates over your coin array. Then from there you will add a string through concatonation [see here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat) to a total string and reply with that string ;).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `msg.reply(coin.join(", "))`. Also `numbers` is not defined and coin is not persistent so, you should use an database such as `enmap` or `mongodb`, etc. Enmap is very simple to use ! [Here is some examples](https://enmap.evie.dev/usage).

*PS: If you are using heroku, you can't use any database*